# mvc mini profiler alternative for vs 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on VS2008 project and it seems that mvc mini profiler does not support it. Do you know any decent alternative with simillar functionalities that will work in my environment?

Comment: Just for the context, the *core* of mvc-mini-profiler shouldn't care about version. The UI elements do use new features, but targeting older frameworks has (over time) increasing cost to support decreasing users. You are welcome to provide a VS2008 compatible branch, of course ;p